# How to make a shell script global?

Tags: macos, shell, unix

I am on Mac's OS 10.6, and I am trying to learn a thing or two about shell scripting. I understand how to save a shell script and make it executable, but I am wondering what I can do or where I can save the file to make it global (that is, accessible no matter what folder I am in).

For example, if I save a .sh file in the /Users/username/ directory and make it executable, I can only execute that script in that specific directory. If I navigate to /Users/username/Downloads, for example, I can't execute the script.

Also, any suggestions of resources for learning more about shell scripting would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Read about the `PATH` environment variable first, then update the question.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

`/usr/local/bin` would be the most appropriate location. Mac OS X has it in the `PATH` by default

Answer (score 61):

There are two ways to do it -

1. Put your script in usr/local/bin and make sure it is executable(chmod +x my_script)(This is already set in the path, you can check by doing an echo $PATH)
2. Create a folder in your home directory called bin. (For your personal scripts)

   - cd ~ (Takes you to your home directory)
   - mkdir bin  (create a bin folder)
   - vim .bash_profile (to set path environment variable)
   - export PATH=~/bin:$PATH (Press i then add this line and then do esc and type :wq)
   - Now you can just type the name of your script and run it from anywhere you want.

** **NOTE**: If you want to run the script with a shortened command rather than typing your entire filename, add the following to your .bash_profile:
`alias myscript='my_script.sh'`
Then you can run the script by simply typing `myscript`. (you can sub in whatever alias you'd like)

Comment: As you're probably using zsh by now, you might want to take a different approach. Add your personal bin directory to the paths by creating the file /etc/paths.d/MyScripts with the contents ```/Users/<some-username>/bin```

Answer (score 46):

Traditionally, such scripts either go in `~/bin` (ie: the bin directory in your home directory) or `/usr/local/bin/` The former means the script will only work for you, the latter is for scripts you want anybody on the system to be able to run.

If you put it in `~/bin`, you may need to add that to your PATH environment variable. `/usr/local/bin` should already be on the path.

Answer (score 8):

This one is super easy if you are familiar with your bashrc file! This will entirely use just your .bashrc file and takes 2 seconds to accomplish.

(I use Arch Linux Manjaro so I use .bashrc located in my home directory)

The code to be placed in your .bashrc file:

```
# Simple bashrc method to launch anything in terminal from any directory

YOURCOMMAND () {
  cd /path/to/directory/containing/your/script/ && ./YOURSCRIPT
}
```

As you can see, first you use the simple 'cd' command and give it the directory of the scripts location, then use '&&' so that you can make the next command executed right after, and finally open your script just as you would normally! Super easy and saved right in your .bash file! :)

Hope I've helped someone!

Sincerely,

AnonymousX

Comment: this is great... and it allows my zsh to autocomplete!

Comment: But if you have different script?

Answer (score 6):

In mac operating system

- Open bash ~/.bashrc file.
- add path of your script in your bashrc file , using
  **export PATH="$PATH:/Users/sher.mohammad/Office/practice/practiceShell"**
- Open your **~./bash_profile** file and add **[[ -s ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc**
- open new terminal window
  Now whenever you will open your terminal your script will be loaded

Comment: why not just put it directly in `.bash_profile`? It's a lot simpler (and that source .bashrc thing never worked for me).

Comment: I researched I found bash_profile is executed when you login , bashrc is used for non login shells , OS X by default like login shells and load bash_profile , so adding in bash_profile will work fine , and if you write in bashrc you have add   [[ -s ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc in bash_profile , to load bashrc when bash_profile run at login time

Answer (score 2):

On using bash shell, write that script as function and then put it to the .bashrc or source the file which containing that function by "source file_name"

Now execute the script by function call in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Either saving it in `/usr/bin` (or any other directory present in `PATH`) or editing `PATH` to include the directory you saved it in will basically make it run in any directory.

Comment: `/usr/bin` can be completely emptied and replaced during an OS upgrade, making your script mysteriously disappear. `/usr/local/bin` is for this purpose, as mentioned by Bryan Oakley. Also see the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY)

Answer (score 0):

from the working directory of 'script.sh'" mv [script.sh] /usr/local/bin"( not tested but seems to be the least complex way IMO.)

Comment: You'll probably need `sudo mv script.sh /usr/local/bin`, as that directory isn't writable without escalating privileges.

Answer (score -2):

You should put it in the global executable directory on your machine. I think that would usually be `/usr/bin` on Unix-based operating systems (this would however most often require super user privileges on that machine).

You could also put it in any other directory that is in the `$PATH` environment variable, although it would only work for those users who have that directory in that variable.

*You can find the value of `$PATH` by typing `echo $PATH` in a shell. The directories are separated by* `:`.

Comment: I'm gonna downvote because /usr/bin is the wrong answer. /usr/local/bin is specifically designed for "local" scripts (ie: ones you create rather than ones that come with the system).